# RSpecで ' Failed to find Chrome binary.'のエラーが解決できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

ポートフォリオ作成の中でRSpecを使ったテストを作成していたのですが以下のエラーが出ました。

開発環境：
Ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.4.3
Mac OS

```
1.1) Failure/Error: visit login_path
      
      Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound:
        Failed to find Chrome binary.
```

自分で調査して以下の解決方法を試しましたがエラーは消えませんでした。
・Gemfileに'webdriver'を記述→bundle
・Google-Chromeと同じバージョンのchrome-driverをインストール

```
$ which chromedriver                    
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

解決方法があればご教授ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：
Feature Specのテストファイルです。

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe '練習記録投稿機能', type: :system do
  describe '投稿一覧表示機能' do
    before do
      #ユーザーAを作成しておく
      user_a = FactoryBot.create(:user, nickname: 'ユーザーA', email: 'a@example.com')
      #作成者がユーザーAである練習記録を作成しておく
      FactoryBot.create(:training_post, training_impression: 'RSpecテスト', user: user_a)
    end
    context 'ユーザーAがログインしているとき' do
      before do
        #ユーザーAでログインする
        visit login_path
        fill_in 'session_email', with: 'a@example.com'
        fill_in 'session_password', with: 'password'
        click_button 'ログインする'
      end
      it 'ユーザーAが作成した練習記録が表示される' do
        #作成済の練習記録が画面上に表示されていることを確認
        expect(page).to have_content 'RSpecテスト'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: 可能であれば、エラーメッセージだけではなくテスト用のコードなども [edit] から追記いただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: `which chromedriver` が通るということは既に設定済みかと思われますが、念のため `$PATH` に `/usr/local/bin` が含まれているかご確認いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: テストファイルを追記いたしました。確認いただけたら嬉しいです。

Comment: $PATHに/usr/local/bin が含まれていることを確認しました。

Comment: 念のための確認なのですが、Google Chrome は `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` としてインストールされていますでしょうか？

Comment: 確認したところ/Applications/Google Chrome２.appとなっており、/Applications/Google Chrome.appに修正したところエラーが消えました！

Comment: おそらく気づかないうちにクロームのインストールを二回した影響でGoogle Chrome２.appを使っていた様です。
ご丁寧に教えていただき本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: なるほど！　もしよければ、その状況の詳細と、どう解決したかを[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)の形で投稿いただけませんでしょうか？　暫く待つと自分の回答を承認することもできるようになります。

Comment: わかりました！自己回答しておきます！

Comment: ご丁寧に答えていただき本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
エラーの原因は本来/Applications/Google Chrome.appであるべきところが/Applications/Google Chrome２.appとなっていたことでした。おそらくPCのセットアップ時にクロームを2回インストールしてしまい、Google Chrome２.appを使用していた様です。